# inexplicable Netbeans serializable warning for nested base class

Tags: java, netbeans, inner-classes, serializable

When I define the following class

```
public class Outer extends Outer.Inner {
    public static class Inner { }
}
```

Netbeans 6.9.1 gives me the "has no definition of serialVersionUID" warning for both Outer and Inner. I'm wondering if there is a legit reason for this warning, or if it's a bug. What about extending an inner class makes the compiler think they are implementing Serializable?

Note: This is more out of curiosity than wanting this unnecessary design pattern.

Comment: Most curious.  Perhaps the compiler isn't able to generate a serialVersionUID because class Inner is in the scope of Outer.

Comment: Eclipse 3.7 gives an error: `Cycle detected: the type Outer cannot extend/implement itself or one of its own member types`.

Comment: NetBeans 13 reports `cyclic inheritance involving Outer` and nothing regarding `serialVersionUID`.

Answer (score 1):

I've wondered the same thing myself. In lieu of an answer, I turned off the warning.

Tools -> Options Menu
Hints Tab -> Standard Javac warnings
Uncheck the serialization checkbox.

Now you'll have to be careful when extending Serialized Objects, but it stops annoying you about things that aren't serialized.