# how to remove the warning The serializable class ClASSNAME does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long

Tags: java

I create a class which extends `Exception` class, I got this warning on Eclipse

> The serializable class PhoneAlreadyExists does not declare a static
>   final serialVersionUID field of type long

how to remove it please ?

```
public class PhoneAlreadyExists extends Exception {
    public PhoneAlreadyExists() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
    }

    PhoneAlreadyExists(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add a `serialVersionUID` field to the class.

Comment: Its just a warning and it won't crash anything. If it really bothers you, you can suppress it by hovering over the warning and clicking the first suggestion (or whichever one says that you can suppress it).

Comment: Have a look at my answer below. That may help.

Comment: Also duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052627/serialversionuid-field-warning-in-eclipse?s=3|92.2522) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881621/understanding-of-findbugs-warning-about-serialversionuid-field?s=7|78.1278) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823477/warning-serial-serializable-class-someclass-has-no-definition-of-serialversio?s=9|72.0586)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078806/inexplicable-netbeans-serializable-warning-for-nested-base-class?s=14|60.2770) and more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add an annotation `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` on your class, to ignore that warning

Comment: Or just *resolve the warning correctly*. It's usually better than ignoring it, even if it is 4 lines of code (including JavaDoc, of course - otherwise it's just 1)

Comment: Of course, but usually we needn't to define serial version, therefore this is quick solution for the problem.

Comment: It's not really quicker. Java IDEs can generate serial version fields using the "quick fix" function. E.g. eclipse.

Comment: Nice suggestion I haven't tried it yet with quick fix :)

Comment: Does someone have a like about this?  I'm wondering if there are other types of "serial" warnings that may be suppressed or if this is the only case.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse every line of code represents intent. If you do not intend the object to be serialized, and you add code to support contrary, you are writing incoherent code. If we adhere to all possible "3 lines of code" changes, the intentional part of your code will end up being minority of your actual code, which is dangerous if you want to write code that you want to be able to come back to later.

It is compiler's, and fragile base class, and typeclass's responsibility to take care of spicing up your classes, not your specific class itself.

Comment: @Dmitry If you don't intend the class to be serializable, then don't implement the `Serializable` interface! It's not the `serialVersionUID` field that *causes* the inconsistency, nor will ignoring the problem solve it. All this field does is help recognize deserialization issues when a class definition changes. Adding it will not "enable" serialization, and ignoring the warning will not prevent serialization.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse As the original poster pointed out, this annoyance can happen when you extend a class that is serializable, which is beyond your control. If a programmer is confident that no `PhoneAlreadyExists` instance will ever be serialized, then the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation is entirely approrpriate.

Comment: Which gains you nothing compared to just having your IDE generate a serial. It won't be detected as a mistake - the class will still implement serializable.

Comment: i generated a serial version and it still says 'The serializable class Window does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long' lmao

Answer (score 22):

To change the behavior in eclipse globally: Go to Preferences->Java->*Compiler*->Errors/Warnings->Potential Programming Problems. There's an entry for this specific problem. You can change it for a specific project too.

That answers your question, although - I'd recommend to leave it at warning level and add the missing fields. Or add the SuppressWarnings annotation to those serializable classes that really do not need the field because they'll never be serialized.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it's Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/warnings -> Potential programming problems

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I've updated my answer with the correct path.

Comment: Funny how the most useful/to the point answers are always left behind, yours should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Note that you get this warning when deriving an anonymous type from some serializable type - even if the supertype _has its own @SuppressWarnings("serial")!!_).  E.g., when using Guava's TypeToken.  (Eclipse 4.4.2.) I suppose I _could_ annotate the site of the new anonymous type ... but it's a PITA and I'd rather turn this nearly useless warning off altogether.

Comment: Do **not** just ignore warnings. In 99% of cases, they are correctly warning you about a problem. Rather fix the root cause instead.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Generally I agree with you, but unless you are serializing your exceptions, sending them over RMI/CORBA or storing them to disk, most people will not encounter problems with exception serialization in most domains. If you are in a domain where you will be affected, you (should) _know_. The 99% will not see issues in their web apps due to this. That's why it should be possible to globally disable this for a project. Too bad there is no globally available fix like `.eslintrc` for Java.

Comment: @oligofren: just add the serial number. That is not at all harder (press Ctrl+1 in Eclipse). And that actually is a **proper solution** for the warning, rather than *ignoring* the cause. Why ignore when there is a one-time auto-generateable fix?

Answer (score 9):

You need to declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long.

Look up the `Serializable` API of Java. Exceptions must implement `Serializable`, and `Serializable` classes must have a `serialVersionUID`:

```
public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Whenever you make incompatible changes to the class, increment this version.

Answer (score 2):

To ignore the warning "The serializable class ClASSNAME does not declare a static final serialVersionUID......" do the following inside eclipse*:

1. Click Window-Preferences-Java-Compiler-Errors/Warnings
2. Click on "Potential Programming Problems"
3. Scroll down to "Serializable class without serialVersionUID"
4. Choose "Ignore"
5. Click Apply
6. Click OK

Save and close your eclipse IDE
When you reopen eclipse, these specific warnings should no longer be listed.

*For this example solution I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Answer (score 1):

just add this code @SuppressWarnings("serial") above your public class PhoneAlreadyExists extends Exception { line

Comment: Please provide additional detail and format your answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to add the serialversionUID in most cases, but eclipse gives the warning on all swing derived classes, which will never be serialized. I tried changing the setting at preferences->Java -> Compiler -> Errors/warnings -> Potential programming problems, but it had no effect. So I guess the best solution would be to suppress the warning on each class that will never be serialized; or grit your teeth and ignore the warning.